# Docker push extremly slow

Tags: docker

A simple docker push takes hours for a simple 117mb image. It isn't a problem for smaller images, so it seems like some sort of throttling.

It is getting pushed to docker hub in a public repository on the free version.

The command is simply:

`docker image push xxx/my-website:latest`
[image]

Update: This had nothing to do with docker. It happened to be my upload speed on my computer which was limited to 100kb/s for some reason. I have no idea why it suddenly was set to that, but that was the problem.

Comment: Have you tried any other registry?

Comment: Docker Hub is occasionally very slow.

Comment: I have some smaller registries, those were uploaded in few seconds. They were just under 100Mb, so it seems as there are some kind of throttling for "bigger" images.

Comment: The pushing literally takes 12 hours, this is unusable...